# How to align numbers in a matrix by decimal point?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, matrices

Here is a matrix:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1.41 & -1.73\\
    2.718 & 3.14
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the number of decimal points may be different, and some numbers are negative. I'd like to have the columns aligned on the decimal points.

Normally, I'd use a half-em space for "missing" digits and a `\hphantom-` - but I use a font where the digits are not the same width, so that is ruled out.

I skimmed through TeX.SE, but only found answers for *tables*, not matrices.  I have also looked in the docs of `amsmath` and `mathtools`, to no avail.

I suspect I could use TikZ matrices for that, but I'd prefer to stay simple if possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Using proportional figures in a table is not the best service to your readers. Even if the decimal points are aligned, the numbers will be difficult to read anyway.

Comment: It's not a table. It's a fairly small (4x4) matrix.

Comment: It makes no difference. Center the numbers and be happy.

Comment: But then it looks terrible.

Answer (score 9):

With `matrix` is not possible (at least easy), try with array with `S` columns, which are defined in the `siunitx` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\[
  \left(\begin{array}{@{} S[table-format=1.3]S[table-format=-1.2] @{}}
    1.41  & -1.73\\
    2.718 &  3.14
  \end{array}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's possible with `matrix` as updated by `mathtools`; just use `S` columntype.

Answer (score 9):

With `nicematrix` and `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{pNiceArray}{S[table-format=1.3]S[table-format=-1.2]}
    1.41  & -1.73\\
    2.718 &  3.14
  \end{pNiceArray}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 5):

The only modification needed to the original post is the use of the `S` columntype.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:1}      
  \begin{pmatrix*}[S]
    1.41  & -1.73 \\
    2.718 & 3.14
  \end{pmatrix*}      
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

The `\phantom` can be used:

```
\def\0{\phantom{0}} \def\+{\phantom{+}}
$$
  \pmatrix{ 1.41\0 &  -1.73 \cr
            2.718  & \+3.14 }
$$
```

Comment: Well, in general you are right, but I explicitly stated that this approach won't work for me in this case.